# SQL case statement order of execution

Tags: sql

Is the `case` statement performed before or after the where clause, and is it before the group by clause? I and find order of operations with the case statement anywhere.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: omg go through the basics of sql

Comment: `case` can be used in any number of places in a sql statement. You'll need to provide your code, your expectations and your current results to get any meaningful help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT <TOP_specification> <select_list>
<case_statements>
FROM <left_table>
<join_type> JOIN <right_table>
ON <join_condition>
WHERE <where_condition>
GROUP BY <group_by_list>
HAVING <having_condition>
ORDER BY <order_by_list>
```

just for ur reference i have added case statements. in a simple query case is executed in the given place.

Comment: what if the `case` is in the `where` or the `group by`, `order by`, `having`. you can even have a `case` in the `on` of a join. these would all be evaluated at different times.

Comment: you are right. i have just given the basics as the questioner does not have basic idea of the execution order

Answer (score 0):

Using an example query...

```
SELECT
    tblfoo.A,
    (CASE 
    WHEN tblfoo.B LIKE 'Hello' THEN 'Greeting'
    WHEN tblfoo.B LIKE 'Goodbye' THEN 'Goodbye'
    ELSE 'Neither' 
    END) AS "Word"

FROM
    tblFoo

WHERE
    tblFoo.Name = 'Example'
```

1. First, the FROM clause is executed to grab all of the available rows
2. Then, the WHERE clause is executed to grab only the applicable rows
3. Then, the SELECT clause is executed to grab the particular data.
4. Therefore, the CASE statement is executed last, when it is selecting that particular column, it will then scan through the column and perform the CASE statement

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: What about group by and if you have aggregate in case statement?

Comment: In the event that a group by is added, the GROUP BY clause would take place after the SELECT aggregated statement